# Drag and drop same item from TreeView to multiple ListBoxes in Silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, drag-and-drop

I understand I can use a TreeViewDragDropTarget to wrap the TreeView and the ListBoxDragDropTarget to wrap the ListBox and then I can drap and drop items from one to the other.

But I am not sure how I can drag an item from the TreeView to the ListBox and don't actually remove the item from the TreeView, as I might need to drag the same item to another ListBox... In another word, I want this TreeView to be fixed, just be able to drag and drop its items around.

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer from the following link.

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/200602/468667.aspx